# ¿Cómo envío carácteres especiales con Sockets TCP?

Tags: java, python, c++, c, socket

Tengo un modelo de programa cliente/servidor escrito en c,c++,java (da igual) y por ejemplo queremos mandar `"Hola\nMundo"` mediante sockets entre el cliente y el servidor.

Para que pueda enviar los caracteres especiales, en este caso `\n`, sin que al recibirlo haya que procesar el texto en busca de estos caracteres especiales, ¿deberia enviar el caracter especial `\n` en su codifición **ASCII** y con él, el resto del texto de tal forma que realmente solo envio números (1 por caracter sea especial o no) ?

O, ¿debería encontrar alguna función (porque es conocido que existe y habitual usarlo) que envie y reciba el texto de tal manera que si le mando a capón `"Hola\nMundo"` al recibir el mensaje e imprimirlo sin más obtenga?:

```
Hola
Mundo
```

Aunque en el caso de la función sí habría que comentar sobre lenguaje, librería, etc.. Me gustaría saber, en general, de qué forma se envian los datos por la red (porque quizás tengas más ventajas que de otra forma (como podría ser el caso de los caracteres especiales) o por lo que sea)

Comment: Si tu transfieres data vía un `Socket` en el fondo siempre transfieres una cantidad de `byte`. Como lo conviertes en otros formatos es a tu criterio. Si necesitas saber mas, trata de preguntar por casos un poco mas concreto, por ejemplo "TCP Socket en Java" o "UDP datagrama en c++"

Comment: se trataría de sockets TCP, como explico en la pregunta la prgunta es tan generica que el lenguaje de alto nivel: c,c++ o java cualquiera valdría pues lo que yo quiero saber es cúal es la forma en la que los desarroladores de código por norma general hacen para enviar sus textos. Y un poco más concreto los caracteres especiales.

Comment: Dudo mucho que te de lo mismo el lenguaje porque para cada uno hay una respuesta diferente (al menos en cuanto a código se refiere). Voto por cerrar la pregunta hasta que acotes un poco la pregunta.

Comment: *escrito en c,c++,java (da igual)*. No. **No da igual**. Cada lenguaje ofrecerá una solución distinta.

Comment: una solución distinta a nivel de métodos, librerías. No en paradigma de la programación. De verdad me acabo de llevar una decepción por la gente que no ha sabido responder a esta pregunta

Comment: @IgnacioCastillejoGomez siento que estés decepcionado. Yo también lo estoy: C, C++, Java y Python son lenguajes **muy distintos** con sintaxis, ámbito y tipo de compilación diferentes (Python ni siquiera es un lenguaje compilado), sólo C++ comparte librerías con otro lenguaje (con C, y dichas librerías se debieron adaptar). No es posible aportar una solución a "*nivel de métodos, librerías*" para lenguajes que son distintos entre si, por muy decepcionante que te parezca.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster es que en la pregunta esta clara, nos busco respuestas de usa este método en este lenguaje o este otro en otro lenguaje, sino a nivel paradigma. En TODOS los lenguajes los programadores como mandan la información. Y Stefan dio la respuesta. Tienes que saber la codificacion comun entre cliente y servidor. Y eso era lo que yo buscaba.

Comment: @IgnacioCastillejoGomez Stefan dió una respuesta válida para Java, pero en Python no tienes `InputStream` en C++ se abre la comunicación de manera diferente según el sistema operativo, C no es orientado a objetos y se hace todo con funciones... así que por mucho "*paradigma*" que estés buscando **cada lenguaje tendrá una respuesta totalmente distinta**.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster pero no te has dado cuenta que no paras de concretar una forma concreta en un lenguaje concreto. Yo busco el paradigma, el pseudocodigo. Podria ser productivo dar tu opinion que es lo que pido (en forma de paradigma) y concretar por ejemplo en tu caso como lo harias con python. Stefan penso en Java y hablo de InputStream porque concreto en Java para ser más especifico en un lenguaje concreto. Creo que esta bastante claro...

Comment: @IgnacioCastillejoGomez si buscas un paradigma, pregunta por un paradigma... no pongas etiquetas de lenguajes al azar en tu pregunta. Si buscas un paradigma no escribas en tu propia pregunta "**escrito en c,c++,java**". Si buscas un paradigma no preguntes sobre una cuestión que requiere **implementación** concreta como apertura de puertos y comunicación TCP. Si buscas un paradigma pregunta sobre [paradigmas de programación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigma_de_programaci%C3%B3n).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster "Aunque en el caso de la función sí habría que comentar sobre lenguaje, librería, etc.. Me gustaría saber, en general, **de qué forma se envian los datos por la red** (porque quizás tengas más ventajas que de otra forma (como podría ser el caso de los caracteres especiales) o por lo que sea)"

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no le voy a dar más vueltas el conocimiento es sabiduría, no entiendo porque parece gustar más buscarle la n-ésima pata al gato que enseñar humildemente a los demas. Como dije, comentamos este tema en la universidad y no hubo ninguna confusión.  Saludos y grácias por las respuestas y comentarios!

Comment: @IgnacioCastillejoGomez estoy encantado de enseñar, y en eso consiste mi insistencia en este tema: estás pidiendo conocimientos de manera incorrecta, centrándote en una cosa pero pidiendo otra; mezclando conceptos y confundiendo terminología. Un paradigma no es lo que estás describiendo. El **tratamiento específico** de datos que solicitas varía según plataforma, lenguaje, sistema operativo y librería... pese a ello **insistes** en pedir pseudo-código y *paradigmas*, dando muestras de que necesitas soluciones específicas pero reclamando conceptos genéricos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En una conexión TCP se transfieren los datos en `byte`. Se envia una cantidad de `byte` y se recibe una cantidad de `byte`.
Lo que representan estos bytes tiene que saber el receptor para transformar los datos crudos en un formato como lo quiere usar.

TCP en si mismo no impone ninguna codificación especial, así si envío por ejemplo textos de un servidor codificado en UTF-8, el cliente tiene que saberlo y transformarse los `byte` que recibe dependiente de las herramientas disponibles del lenguaje de programación usado.

Por ejemplo, si recibí un arreglo de `byte` en `Java`, puedo convertirlo en un `String` con la codificación por defecto del cliente así:

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] bytes = new byte[is.available()];
is.read(bytes); 
String recibido =  new String(bytes);
```

Si por ejemplo recibo texto en utf-8 y por defecto uso utf-16, puedo remplazar la forma de construir el `String` dando un `Charset` para la conversión.

```
String recibido = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Espero que eso aclara tu duda.

a propósito:
`LINEFEED` o "\n" es perfectamente representable como byte, es el valor 10.

```
System.out.println("\n".codePointAt(0));

10
```

Comment: PERFECTO, gracias esto era lo que yo necesitaba. Como bien me has comentado es necesario saber la codificación común entre cliente y servidor por lo que habría que enviarlo en formato de bytes. Mi problema con \n es que mandaba dos caracteres: '\' y 'n' muy lejos del valor ASCII 10 que correctamente comentas. Gracias!!!

Comment: @IgnacioCastillejoGomez si te enviaba por separado los caracteres "\" y "n" sería por leer de una fuente de texto que contuviera literalmente dichos caracteres en lugar de un salto de línea literal... ¿posiblemente de un archivo de texto?